# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

This is probably simple but I cant find the explanation and it happens to me all the time.

I am trying to selected values from column `Rate1E` that are over `3.5` and view the rest of the rows in pandas DataFrame `energy` for selected rows meeting criteria as stated above. I had someone give me an answer before and have simply changed to text as follows:

```
energy = energy.loc[energy[:, 'Rate1E'] >= 3.5]
print(energy.loc[:, 'Rate1E'])
```

However once again I have found myself with the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Online solutions suggest `.loc` is the answer. Would someone know how to fix the code or better yet explain to me why I always seem to get that error.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, `df[x, y, z]` treats `x, y, z` as a tuple that represents a label when the column index is a `MultiIndex`. In this case it's trying to use `:`, i.e., `slice(None)` as a label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You need:

```
energy = energy.loc[energy['Rate1E'] >= 3.5]
```

Alternatively:

```
energy = energy.loc[energy.loc[:, 'Rate1E'] >= 3.5]
```

The crucial point is `energy.loc[:, 'Rate1E']` and `energy['Rate1E']` are series, the latter being a convenient way to access the former.

It is unfortunate, but the Pandas documentation doesn't specify precisely permitted arguments for `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`, for which `df[]` is syntactic sugar. The most popular uses are:

- Provide a string to give a series.
- Provide a list to give a dataframe.
- Provide a Boolean series to filter your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your call of `energy[:, 'Rate1E']` is doing something different to what you expect.  You're looking for a `.loc[]` call.

```
energy = energy.loc[energy['Rate1E'] >= 3.5]
print(energy['Rate1E'])
```

Comment: Solution is incorrect as `.loc` call needed after initial square brackets.

Comment: For solution see above

Comment: I am trying to view all other columns in `energy` that is based on values in `unitRate1Elec` that are greater or equal to 3.5.

Comment: @geds133 Yes, that is what the proposed answer does.  @jpp has done a great job of summarizing why you can use both both `energy.loc[]`  or `energy[]` inside your first `energy.loc[]` call.  Either way it looks like your problem is solved :)